# CSV Values in Dynamic PIVOT's IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic pivot query , which uses csv values in the condition statements .I created a function (splitstring("ABC,sd",",")) which split the csv string and returns in a tabular form, Function is working in the 'IN' clause condtion except inside the 'PIVOT' statement..

```sql
insert into @filteredUsers  select * from @users users
 Where (
    (@IncludeInactiveUsers = 1 AND ( users.Status = 'Active' OR (users.Status = 'Inactive')) )
 OR (@IncludeInactiveUsers = 0 AND  users.Status = 'Active')
)


SELECT @columns = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(NAME)
            FROM @filteredUsers
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SELECT @SelectedColumns = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ', ''N'') AS [' + NAME + ']'
            FROM @filteredUsers
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');



DECLARE @loanProgramChannels TABLE (
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,NAME VARCHAR(500)
    ,[Broker] VARCHAR(2)
    ,[Correspond] VARCHAR(2)
    ,[Retail] VARCHAR(2)
    );
insert into @loanProgramChannels  select
        id,
        [Loan Program Name],
        ISNULL([Broker],'N') as [Broker],
        ISNULL([Correspond],'N') as [Correspond],
        ISNULL([Retail],'N') as [Retail]
    FROM
        (
            SELECT LoanPrograms.Id
            , LoanPrograms.NAME AS [Loan Program Name]
            , ' Y ' AS Y
            , Channels.NAME AS [ChannelType]
            FROM LoanPrograms
            LEFT JOIN LoanProgramChannels ON LoanPrograms.id = LoanProgramChannels.Loanprogram_Id
            LEFT JOIN Channels ON Channels.id = LoanProgramChannels.Channel_id
        ) programs
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(Y) FOR [ChannelType] IN ([Broker],[Correspond],[Retail])
        )PivotTable

SELECT Name,Broker,Correspond,Retail,  @SelectedColumns 
FROM
(
    SELECT LoanPrograms.NAME
    ,LP.[Broker]
    ,LP.[Correspond]
    ,LP.[Retail]
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN UserParameterValues.value IS NULL
                THEN ' N '
            ELSE ' Y '
            END
        ) AS value
    ,(users.FirstName + space(1) + users.LastName) FullName
    FROM LoanPrograms
    LEFT JOIN UserParameterValues ON LoanPrograms.id = UserParameterValues.ValueId
    LEFT JOIN Parameters on UserParameterValues.ParameterId = Parameters.id 
        AND Parameters.Name = 'UwHierarchy'
    LEFT JOIN users ON UserParameterValues.UserId = Users.Id
    LEFT JOIN @loanProgramChannels LP ON LP.id = loanPrograms.id


) AS UsersTable
PIVOT 
(
SUM(value)
  FOR FullName IN( SELECT *
                FROM dbo.SplitString(@UserNames, ',' ) ) AS pvt
```

Not sure how can I use the same function inside my PIVOT statements IN clause..?

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` clause in the `Pivot` clause is not the same as the `IN` operator in `Where` clause.
It specifies the columns of the pivot, and SQL Server expects a constant list of columns, and not a table.
In order to make this pivot query to work properly you must use dynamic sql.

I was going to try and re-write your code, but I'm not so sure what columns you need to use in the pivot, so I'll just give you this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/) that explains dynamic pivot technique in sql server.